# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a program in visual to use a database to make a PC builder type program.  When I try to insert data into the `PROCESSORS` table, I get the following error:

> ERROR:
>       Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Since my other inserts work fine, I don't know what's wrong with this one.

```
DROP TABLE PROCESSORS
DROP TABLE MOTHERBOARDS
DROP TABLE SOCKET_TYPE
DROP TABLE STORE;

CREATE TABLE PROCESSORS (
PRODCUT_ID      VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
BRAND           VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
CORES           INTEGER NOT NULL,
SPEED           DECIMAL NOT NULL,
INTEGRATED_GPU  VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE STORE(
STORE_ID        VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
PRODUCT_ID      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_NAME    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
STORE           VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRICE           INTEGER     NOT NULL);

/*Newegg Product I7-4470*/
INSERT INTO PROCESSORS VALUES('BX80646I74770','Intel',4,3.4,'None');
INSERT INTO STORE VALUES('N82E16819116900','BX80646I74770','Intel Core I7-4470 Haswell','Newegg',309.99);
```

Comment: are other rows being entered into this table properly? Are you accidentlly repeating the primary key?

Comment: Presumably, it all works fine when usig the mysql client directly

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're entering a decimal in to an integer in the STORE Price column :)

Edit: Just noticed the DECIMAL type of the column is missing the impelementation syntax, e.g. DECIMAL(2,2). As it stands, according to [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) the default when not provided is DECIMAL(10, 0) which is a 10 digit integer basically. Provide precise parameters to the DECIMAL data type to allow the correct numbers with decimal places to be added, this will fix the INSERT problem.

Comment: I still have an error for When I try to enter data into the Processor table though, not the store table :[

Comment: Do I need to have parameters when I declare the DECIMAL data type? I left it blank? Also what would the parameter be?

Comment: You beat me to it! Just added to my answer :)

Comment: :) no problem, could you mark me as the answer please? I'm trying to build up my reputation on SO. Thanks! :)

Comment: If you don't specify the precision and scale for DECIMAL, it defaults to `DECIMAL(10,0)`. Also, don't use FLOAT unless you want confusing rounding behavior. Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-float.html